# android detect user modifying device clock time

Tags: android, datetime, android-ndk

My App requires correct time (can not rely on device time since the user can change it + carrier might be not available or doesnt support NITZ). Initially I use http calls to a trusted server, however there are situations when network is not available.

Is there any other option I can use?

Can I rely on broadcast ACTION_TIME_CHANGED to detect that the user modofied the device clock? Does my app always need to be running in order to get this notification (this I would like to avoid)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My App requires correct time

Never rely on the client for accurate time, on any platform.

> Initially I use http calls to a trusted server, however there are situations when network is not available.

Then you cannot have accurate time, by definition.

> Is there any other option I can use?

You can create your own firmware that prevents the user from setting the time.

> Can I rely on broadcast ACTION_TIME_CHANGED to detect that the user modofied the device clock?

No, insofar as there are several possible reasons why that broadcast will be sent.

> Does my app always need to be running in order to get this notification (this I would like to avoid)?

I can tell you that the only receivers of ACTION_TIME_CHANGED that I see in the Android source code are ones that register for it via `registerReceiver()`, not the manifest. This broadcast does not fit the usual  pattern where `registerReceiver()` is required, though. It is probably simpler for you to just try it.