# Know the old time

Tags: android, time

I want to design app in which I can get the time before the user has changed to any new time.
I am using

```
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
```

To know that user has changed time

eg. Suppose current time is 10.00 pm User changed it to 09.00 pm So can i get previous time that is 10.00 pm

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: So can i get previous time that is 10.00 pm ?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: My app is time dependent and I am blocking a app in let 9pm to 11pm but if user changed time to something else when it is 10pm thats why I want to know correct time.

Comment: You want the app to execute between 10pm to 11pm?

Comment: Yes but if user changed time to 12 when the current time is 10 how can i avoid it

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230951/718.

Comment: I think above link will let me know that user has changed the time but how can i know that what was the previous time from which he changed to newone

Comment: Why do you need to that? Just check if the current time is within 10-11pm.

Comment: @jfs Imagine a scenario that I want to block user's some activity from 8 pm to 10pm, so when time reaches to 7.30pm he changes time to let say 2pm and now hi will use that activity for 3 hrs and again changes time back to whatever hi want  so he will keep using activity in between 8pm to 10pm and every time how can I solve this problem  . . .

Comment: @Tushar: Did u find any solution for this problem yet? To get the previous time just before it was changed?

Answer (score 2):

Question was asked some time ago, but I have generally the same problem and cannot find reasonable (efficient) solution.

Just to recall, I want to know the time that was set before user changed time. For example, user changed time from 6:12 PM to 3:21 PM. To the best of my knowledge, there is no information about previous time in `android.intent.action.TIME_SET`. But when handling this intent I want to somehow know that the time was set to 3:21 PM when there actually was 6:12 PM.(let assume the same day).

According to accepted answer to this question:

[android detect user modifying device clock time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877707/android-detect-user-modifying-device-clock-time)

If I want to handle situations when network is not available, I have to kind of append my own timer to my application, measure time on my own, and when handling

```
android.intent.action.TIME_SET
```

get old time from this built-in timer.

But it seems to me, that this is quite heavy solution and I reckon there must be simpler way to do this.

So the question is, what is the best (most efficient and the most simple) way to handle situation described above. Despite this problem seems to me very common, I couldn't find fair solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to monitor the difference between [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) and [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29). The value of System.currentTimeMillis() would be affected by the change of system time whereas the value of SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() would not.